# Add parameter to socialite callback url

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, laravel, oauth

I want to integrate facebook with my app. I'm using laravel/socialite package to get access to facebook page. At all it works but I'm doing it with logged in user and I want to add info from his facebook profile to exsisting account. I'm using Oauth 2 to login to laravel app via user credentials because it's Angular/Laravel app. I need to retrive logged in user to add info to his account but i can't get logged user id. I need to pass extra parameter to `get` method in facebook callback route. And my question is is there any way to add extra parameters to facebook callback url? Here is what I have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/facebook/login', function(){
        Config::set('services.facebook.redirect', 'http://taggers.dev/facebook/callback?access_token='.Session::get('access_token'));
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->with(['asdadad' => 'asd'])->redirect();
    });
    Route::get('facebook/callback', ['middleware' => ['oauth', 'oauth-user'], function(Authorizer $authorizer){
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $uid = $user->getId();

        if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');
        $profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
        if (empty($profile)) {
            // $user_id= Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId(); // the token user_id
            $auth_user = User::where('idUser', $user_id)->first();

            $profile = new Profile();
            $profile->uid = $uid;
            $profile->username = $user->getName();
            $profile = $auth_user->profiles()->save($profile);
        }

        dd($auth_user);
    }]);
});
```

And here is my error:

```
Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1001186793295886&client_secret=b792ea0354c3846225bc70ac7185e54f&code=AQA1xjbQ25a9qE0loN-yjhmOBYBZLtNVcnCLIeCwJV1enion4ysKkpuBqBmZLhpT2I4VkemXr6R9IwcgSVVzqOLMmzvz_SHga9KrK3ny5cLGi0VGmEibNqGSHA9B9jJ9aFt6vA8lQ1r0IqdN94S-KFjpBimzVmT1OoeI-pCayVRG_v_6uYzeQfZAtDXh3BDVTutLaDXUdJEY3sQhop7Qr8n6jARGBYRZgDcXS6Ci69vY3aRoCLsrFdAQlD7Kid0W9QqeSBxbWrc76Ldp06PtdVLMRdQ54qQepwG4mOhOiy40-azn3YIBriSx7o0PcNBBE_f_8vmnbiESlo7R-8Su_7vs&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftaggers.dev%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you (truncated...)
```